# How to check if list returned by Json path contains only 1 unique value

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured, hamcrest, web-api-testing

Json response:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "object": {
        "id": "myId"
      }
    },
    {
      "object": {
        "id": "myId"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to assert that "id" does not have any other value except "myId" using rest assured assertion with hamcrest matcher?

Other sample assertion:
response.then().assertThat().body("result", hasSize(greaterThan(0)));

Currently I am doing this by creating a set from the response and asserting that it has size 1 using testNG assertion but I want to achieve the same with restAssured assertion and hamcrest matcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use method `body`, then solution is:

```
.body("result.object.id", everyItem(is("myId")));
```